# VBA conditional formatting of rows based on cell text value

Tags: vba, excel, row, conditional-formatting

The order of my data from my query comes out as desired - Column A asc, Column B asc.

```
Code       Completion Date Receipt 
P81800A1    09/03/2018   167,000.00 
P81800A1    14/03/2018   178,000.00 
P82080A     12/03/2018   352,500.00 
P83103C1    02/03/2018   570,000.00 
P83103C1    02/03/2018   358,000.00 
P83103C1    02/03/2018   357,500.00 
P83103C1    12/03/2018   340,000.00 
P83103C1    12/03/2018   457,000.00 
P83103C1    13/03/2018   415,000.00 
P83180C1    06/03/2018   645,000.00 
P83180C1    06/03/2018   520,000.00
```

This means if I get a completion for P81800A1 on 15/03/18 when I refresh the data, it will go in between lines 2 and 3 of above.

I have tried to summarise my goal in the attached image.
I want to VBA Conditional format each row based on the cell value of A in that row. Ie P81800A1 rows have one colour. All distinct codes have the same colour. The actual colour does not matter.

[image: 3 Image summary]

I want to do it in VBA so it is robust. I do not want to be creating any additional columns and basing it on formula in standard conditional formatting.

Comment: *I do not want to be creating any additional columns and basing it on formula in standard conditional formatting* why not?

Comment: I struggle with it and not so good at INDIRECT formula. Also when trying to apply to arrange it gets too fiddly with locking certain cells and error proofing. I also feel adding additional columns is not the proper way for a data analyst. If you can help me on that, then appreciated, otherwise prefer to put it in worksheet code.

Comment: Ok, You want in in VBA then. Please, post the code you have tried, and where are you stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not perfect but a reasonable start. It uses a dictionary to collect the unique codes and randbetween with dictionary item count to generate an associated colour. Conditional formatting rules are applied using the distinct codes.

Notes:

- You might want to improve the random colour generation part (at present range is limited and you may occasionally get very dark formats - though you could run the macro again)
- Make range selection more robust as start position is hard coded at present and later parts of code use this start position as well
- Required, for early binding, reference to Microsoft scripting runtime to be added via VBE>Tools>References. I have included one example of how to use late binding (commented out). If using late binding you would need to specify Object instead of Dictionary for parameters and function return types (where dictionary returned).

Assumes data starts in A2 at present (sheet 9)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatMatchingCodes()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Sheet9")       'change as appropriate

    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = GetLastRow(wsTarget)

    Dim formatRange As Range

    If Not lastRow <= 2 Then

        Set formatRange = wsTarget.Range("A2:C" & lastRow) 'Excludes header row
    Else
        MsgBox "End row is before start row"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary
    Set codeColoursDictionary = GetDistinctCodeCount(formatRange.Value2)

    wsTarget.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    AddFormatting formatRange, codeColoursDictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Function GetDistinctCodeCount(ByVal sourceData As Variant) As Dictionary 'as object if latebound

''LATE binding
'    Dim distinctDict As Object
'    Set distinctDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

''Early binding add reference to VBE > tools > references > Microsoft scripting runtime
    Dim distinctDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set distinctDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentCode As Long

    For currentCode = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)

        If Not distinctDict.exists(sourceData(currentCode, 1)) Then
            distinctDict.Add sourceData(currentCode, 1), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(13434828, 17777777) + distinctDict.Count
        End If

    Next currentCode

    Set GetDistinctCodeCount = distinctDict
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet) As Long

    With wsTarget
           GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'change to column containing last row up to which you want to format
    End With

End Function

Public Sub AddFormatting(ByVal formatRange As Range, ByVal codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary)  'note pass as object if late binding

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim counter As Long

    For Each key In codeColoursDictionary.Keys

        counter = counter + 1

        With formatRange

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A2=""" & key & """"
            .FormatConditions(counter).StopIfTrue = False

            With .FormatConditions(counter).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = codeColoursDictionary(key)
                ' .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End With

    Next key

End Sub
```

Data in sheet after run:

[image: Formatting]

Version 2 for OP

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatMatchingCodes2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Sheet9")       'change as appropriate

    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastRow = GetLastRow(wsTarget)

    Dim formatRange As Range

    If Not lastRow <= 2 Then

        Set formatRange = wsTarget.Range("A2:G" & lastRow) 'Excludes header row
    Else
        MsgBox "End row is before start row"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary
    Set codeColoursDictionary = GetDistinctCodeCount(formatRange.Value2)

    wsTarget.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    AddFormatting formatRange, codeColoursDictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Function GetDistinctCodeCount(ByVal sourceData As Variant) As Dictionary 'as object if latebound

''LATE binding
'    Dim distinctDict As Object
'    Set distinctDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

''Early binding add reference to VBE > tools > references > Microsoft scripting runtime
    Dim distinctDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set distinctDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currentCode As Long

    For currentCode = LBound(sourceData, 1) To UBound(sourceData, 1)

        If Not distinctDict.exists(sourceData(currentCode, 5)) Then
            distinctDict.Add sourceData(currentCode, 5), Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(13434828, 17777777) + distinctDict.Count
        End If

    Next currentCode

    Set GetDistinctCodeCount = distinctDict
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet) As Long

    With wsTarget
           GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row 'change to column containing last row up to which you want to format
    End With

End Function

Public Sub AddFormatting(ByVal formatRange As Range, ByVal codeColoursDictionary As Dictionary)  'note pass as object if late binding

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim counter As Long

    For Each key In codeColoursDictionary.Keys

        counter = counter + 1

        With formatRange

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$E2=""" & key & """"
            .FormatConditions(counter).StopIfTrue = False

            With .FormatConditions(counter).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = codeColoursDictionary(key)
                ' .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End With

    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr, thank you very much! This is what I am looking for. It's working for me. Thanks also for the improvement tips.

Comment: It was a bit naughty of me to write if for you but it was an interesting idea I haven't tried before. Enjoy developing it!

Comment: QHarr this is a bit amateur but in my actual data, it's column E that I want distincts to be based off. How can I edit the code to take this rather than A? I have tried editing through trial and error, but have not been successful.

Comment: My Data is A:L with Code in E. If I change my output to Code in A, the formatting works. But I want Code to remain in E.

Comment: Ok see version 2

Comment: You're a star! Thank you. I'll be studying the code to learn off it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166984/discussion-between-qharr-and-dasal-kalubowila).